# colorbox custom caption via field collection

Tags: entities, javascript

I want to have a content type with a field collection of an image and a text field. The image is to be displayed via Colorbox, the text field is to be used as the caption for the image.
I am sure I achieved this without problems before.
When I want to chose the relevant token for the custom image caption in cbox, the token browser does not allow me to use the other field. Only the current date, page use, files, random and site information token groups are available (see image below).
What am i doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One needs to enable the entity API / entity token (included in Entity API) modules. The field collection text fields become available to tokens and can thus be used as captions.